# CMake change forced DESTINATION directory name (install target)

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm trying to add `install` target to my library. I have my source code & header files located in sub-directories under `src/`.

Relevant chunk of my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
install(
    TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}"
    EXPORT ionir-config LIBRARY
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # Destination is relative to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}.
)

install(
    EXPORT ionir-config
    NAMESPACE ionir::
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ionir
)

install(
    DIRECTORY src
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" PATTERN "LICENSE" # Match only header files & LICENSE file.
)
```

The problem is that once installed, the output directory's name is `src`:

[image: directory output as src instead of ionir]

I would like it to be `ionir`, otherwise I'd have to import files like this:

```cpp
#include <ionir/src/something/file.h>
                ^^^
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For avoid adding directory name to installation path, terminate the directory with a **slash** (`/`):

```
install(
    DIRECTORY src/
    ...
)
```

This is explicitly stated in the documentation for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/install.html#directory) command:

> The last component of each directory name is appended to the destination directory but a trailing slash may be used to avoid this because it leaves the last component empty.